# Safely appending user input in log file

Tags: c#, security, logging, log4net, code-injection

There are many situations that a developer wants to include a value based on user input in the log file, to allow later investigation for problems (i.e. what input caused the error condition).

This can lead to a Log Injection attack (see [this](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Log_injection)), allowing users to put arbitrary content in the log files, fake log entries, or even try to attack the monitoring user / system.

Is there a standard way to **sanitize / encode / escape** user input for appending to the log file?

Note: I'm using log4net and C#, but I think the subject is not limited to a specific environment and platform.

Answer (score 2):

TL;DR  I think we can say that there is no ür-sanitize method that will fit eveyone's needs.

From the OWASP link:

> The most effective way to deter such an attack is to ensure that any external input being logged adheres to strict rules as to what characters are acceptable. As always, white-list style checking is far preferable to black-list style checking.

But looking for a recommended sanitize procedure from OWASP mainly returns information from the [data validation](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Data_Validation) page. Which sounds sensible since input sanitization would depend on what is authorized from the user, what is logged, where it is viewed, etc...

In the given example, removing linebreaks would be sensible, but may not be adequate to log multi-line inputs. White-listing depends on your functionnal needs.